# Transforming rank constraints over positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-rank, semidefinite-programming

For $A, B \in S_{n\times n}$, $i$.$e$. symmetric matrices. Consider the following program

$$
\begin{align}
\underset{ Y \in S_{n \times n} }{ \text{Find} } \quad & Y \succeq 0 \\
s.t. \quad & \langle A,Y  \rangle = a_{1} \\
& Y \succeq  0 \\
& \langle B,Y \rangle \leq b_{1} \\
&\operatorname{Rank} (Y) =  s    
\end{align}
$$
$s$ is just some number less than $n$, for simplicity, assume it is $n-1$ or $n - 2$.

> Is there a way to transform the rank constraint to something that is easier to deal with? For $rank(Y) \leq s$, we can just factor $Y$ into $UU^{\top}$, where $U \in M_{n \times s}$. However, I'm not sure how should I bound the inequality in the other way.

Utimaltely, this is an application to a first-order algorithm I know that would solve $\underset{ Q \succeq 0   }{ min }\|\mathscr{A}Q-b\|$ very fast (under some conditions). Factoring $Q = UU^{\top}$ is in fact used in the algorithm, but for the other way, I'm not exactly sure how to transform the constraints.

I posted [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783207/rank-constraints-in-dual-program) about finding the dual of the above program, which might not related.

Comment: The rank constraint is not convex and is difficult to consider in general. There are many papers that describe how to relax the problem into a form that is simpler to use. Yet, equivalence can be lost.

Comment: @KBS Thank you. As I'm using a weak alternative in the first place, I don't really need equivalence. Do you have any specific sources on how to relax it in this case?

Comment: Check https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4303234 or https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/OPT-009